# pass json using servlet to ajax for displaying google chart

Tags: ajax

I am writing small web application in which i am taking data from MySQL converting it into json format .Then there is a jsp page in which ajax makes call for data on server and and once data is there json is converted into javascript array type to be compatible with Google chart API. In.In this i am able to retrieve data from MySQL and change that into json format but my ajax is not getting called

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome developer tools  or similar tool  and see whats the error being thrown by javascript, and share those details ,...
that info would be useful to find out what is wrong....